# Not getting parameters from openlayer 2 -request to django 1.11

Tags: django, python-2.7, openlayers, geodjango, django-1.11

I am using openlayers 2, Python2.7 & Django 1.11. For a search, I need to send a request with parameters from openlayers(javascript) to Django 1.11.
I am able to submit the request but the parameters are not getting. My code is:

Javascript:

```
var params = ''
var opnLyrRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
params = 'pid=15&ctype=25&stype=50'
opnLyrRequest.open('POST','/test/search/',true); 
opnLyrRequest.onreadystatechange=function(){ 
    if(opnLyrRequest.readyState==4 && opnLyrRequest.status==200){ 
    if(pinGeoJsonFrmt.read(opnLyrRequest.responseText)!=null){  
        dataLoc = pinGeoJsonFrmt.read(opnLyrRequest.responseText);
        if (dataLoc.length > 0) alert("Found !!"); 
        else alert("No Data Found !!"); 
    } 
    }     
} 
opnLyrRequest.send(params);
```

And the Django code working on the above request is:

```
@csrf_exempt
def searchSubmit(request):
    print request
    print request.method
    print request.POST
    print request.GET
    # print request.POST["pid"] #results in MultiValueDictKeyError: "'pid'"
    ....
    ....
```

The getting output like this:

```
<WSGIRequest: POST '/test/search/'>
POST
<QueryDict: {}>
<QueryDict: {}>
```

**The parameters are missing !!**

Comment: If you're doing all this manually, you probably need to set the content-type: `opnLyrRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`.

Comment: it worked !!! :) thanks a lot @DanielRoseman